# Boundedness of composition of 3 functions.

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

If $f,g,h$ are functions defined on $\mathbb{R},$ the function $(f\circ g \circ h)$ is bounded:

i) If $f$ is bounded.

ii) If $g$ is bounded.

iii) If $h$ is bounded.

iv) Only if all the functions $f,g,h$ are bounded.

Shall I take different examples of functions and see?

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: As a first step, what do you think the boundedness of $f$ has to say about the boundedness of the composition?

Comment: what is the relation between boundedness of $f$ and that of the composition? @Kutz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\Im f\circ g\circ h\subseteq\Im f$, the boundedness of $f\circ g\circ h$ is controlled by $f$.

For ii), let $f(x)=1/x$, $g(x)=h(x)=x$, $x\in(0,1)$, both $g$ and $h$ are bounded, but $f\circ g\circ h=f$ is still unbounded.

The rest should be similar.

Comment: what is the meaning of the symbol written after the word As? how is the rest similar and why the boundedness is controlled by $f$, could you provide details please?

Comment: The image of the map.

Comment: The control: if $x$ is in the domain of $h$, then $f\circ g\circ h(x)=f(g(h(x)))$, so $g(h(x))$ is in the domain of $f$, so $f(g(h(x)))$ is in the image of $f$, so the whole thing is controlled by the bound of $f$